# Repair Disk failed

Tags: terminal, permission, error, repair, disk-format

I try to repair a disk because my Mac still is on grey screen during start. I created a USB Yosemite bootable and I can use Terminal.
I tried with:

```
diskutil repairvolume disk0s2
```

But I get the following error:

> Underlying error: 8: POSIX reports: Exec format error

I don't want to format because I have a lot of documents and photos.

Here are the outputs of `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                    TYPE NAHE                  SIZE        IDENTIFIER        
   0:  GUID_partition_scheme                       *500.1 GB    disk0             
   1:                    EFI EFI                    209.7 MB    disk0s1           
   2:              Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           499.8 GB    disk0s2           
/dev/disk1                                                                     
   #:                    TYPE NAME                  SIZE        IDENTIFIER        
   0:   GUID_partition_scheme                       *8.1 GB    disk1             
   1:                    EFI EFI                   209.7 MB    disk1s1           
   2:              Apple_HFS OS X Base System        7.7 GB    disk1s2           
/dev/disk2-disk14 are temporary disks of the OS X Base System (disk1s2)

-bash-3.2# gpt -r show /dev/disk0                                              
         start       size index contents                                           
             0          1       PMBR                                                     
             1          1       Pri GPT header                                           
             2         32       Pri GPT table                                            
            34          6                                                          
            40     409600    1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B   
        409640  976101344    2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC  
     976510984     262151                                                          
     976773135         32       Sec GPT table                                      
     976773167          1       Sec GPT header
```

**UPDATE**

I tried also this [link](http://osxdaily.com/2013/08/07/how-to-repair-a-mac-disk-with-fsck-from-single-user-mode/) but when I do  `fsck -fy`  I Get `Exited With Signal 8`

Comment: @klanomath http://postimg.org/image/fpnmcwlkl/ thanks

Comment: @klanomath Do you mean my Usb bootable or my Hd ?

Comment: @klanomath But I use Usb for use Recovery Hd, Maybe I don't understand sorry

Comment: Usually you have a third partition with the size 1269536 blocks on disk0 which is your Recovery HD. How did you install your current system? Did you clone it form another Mac?

Comment: @klanomath it isn't my mac, it is mac of my friend, and I don't think she clone another mac. Classic Installation, and I don't know which OS is on

Comment: Can you mount disk0s2? `diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk0s2`

Comment: @klanomath Yes I can

Comment: i made a mistake. First I have written disk0s1 but I meant disk0s2. Please repeat the command with disk0s2.

Comment: I can't do it `diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk0s2` failed to mount, If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29541/discussion-between-klanomath-and-barno).